# Difficulty with Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am attempting an integration of the following form:
$$
\frac{1}{3}\int^\infty_0 \frac{x}{%
\,\sqrt{\,{1- \left[\left(A - Bx^{2} - Cx^{4} - Dx^{6}\right)/\left(Ex^{6}\right)\right]^{2}}\,}\,}
\,{\rm d}x
$$

Where A,B,C,D,E are real constants

The result either with or without the limits does not give a result. For the indefinite integral Wolfram alpha states this integral cannot be solved with standard mathematical functions. I have been recommended such methods as steepest descent to try and solve this.
I was wondering if anyone has encountered a similar integral and which method is the most beneficial to solve such a problem.

My initial idea was to compute a series expansion to a suitable order and integrate it that way, but there would be an issue with the limits in this case

Comment: If e.g. $A/E>0$ or $D/E<-1$, the integrand isn't real for all $x>0$.

Comment: Further, if $D/E > -1$, I think the integral diverges -- the denominator gets a nonzero asymptote, and you end up integrating $~kx$ for some $k>0$

Comment: Are you trying to get a symbolic form, evaluate a single specific case, or get a suggested method of numeric evaluation you can apply for various values?

Comment: ideally looking for some sort of symbolic form, but a method that would allow looking at the different cases and overall result if there was to be one etc.

Comment: Looking at it more, I think it always diverges -- when $D/E=-1$, the denominator goes to $+0$, which just makes the integral grow faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral diverges for any choice of constants $A, B, C, D, E$. In short, this is because of the behavior for large $x$. The numerator of the integrand tends to $\infty$, while in the limit the denominator tends to
$$ \sqrt{1 - \left( -\frac{D}{E} \right)^2}. $$
Regardless of what this denominator tends to (finite, zero, or some branch of complex square roots) the denominator doesn't temper the growth of the numerator.